# JS validate custom rule for checking array not empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array called fileQueue.

```
    var fileQueue = [];
```

How can I write a custom rule for js validate to check something is in the array?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean just checking the length, or checking that there's some item in the array that isn't null?

Comment: I want to use js.validate

Comment: Now what exactly is "js.validate"?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(fileQueue.length == 0)
  //empty
else
  //non-empty
```

Comment: Sorry this answer does not use js.validate

Comment: I did. How can I write a custom rule for js validate

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $.inArray() function.

**HTML:**

```
<div>"John" found at <span></span></div>
<div>4 found at <span></span></div>
<div>"Karl" not found, so <span></span></div>
<div>"Pete" is in the array, but not at or after index 2, so <span></span></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>var arr = [ 4, "Pete", 8, "John" ];
  var $spans = $("span");
  $spans.eq(0).text(jQuery.inArray("John", arr));
  $spans.eq(1).text(jQuery.inArray(4, arr));
  $spans.eq(2).text(jQuery.inArray("Karl", arr));
  $spans.eq(3).text(jQuery.inArray("Pete", arr, 2));
</script>
```

**Result**

> "John" found at 3
>   4 found at 0
>   "Karl" not found, so -1
>   "Pete" is in the array, but not at or after index 2, so -1

Take a look at [jQuery.inArray() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: Sorry this answer does not use js.validate

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if(fileQueue.length == 0)
{ 
 //error
 return false;
}
```